# How can I get rid of white spaces at the beginning and end of req.body.field in express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

The body parser in app.js is:

```
var bodyParser=require("body-parser")// version "body-parser": 
                                               "^1.18.2",
...
 //parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 //parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

A AJAX script in a HTML:

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest()
...
xhr.send('field='+field);
```

I have a request body in express to retrieve the post message:

```
app.post('/myRoute',function(req,res){
           var result=JSON.stringify(req.body.field,null,2)// result.split("")=",s,o,m,e,t,h,i,n,g,"
           ....
    })
```

Annoyingly I got a white space at the beginning and end of the returning value of *JSON.stringify(req,body.field,null,2)*

I tried to apply the js trim() method: result.trim(), but no result:

```
JSON.stringify(req.body.field,null,2).trim().split("") returns ",s,o,m,e,t,h,i,n,g,"
```

Comment: Why are you stringifying?, are sure you don't want to parse..  `JSON.parse`

Comment: try JSON.stringify(req.body.field).trim().split("")

Comment: We should know what `field` variable is when you do `xhr.send('field='+field);`?

Answer (score 0):

When you `stringify` a string you end up with a double quoted string, so when you `split` it you don't have extra whitespaces but extra double quotes.

```js
const string = "toto";
console.log(string); // toto

const stringifiedString = JSON.stringify(string);
console.log(stringifiedString); // "toto"

const split = stringifiedString.split("");
console.log(split); // ['"', "t", "o", "t", "o", '"']
```

As @Keith pointed out, why are you stringifying ?

Comment: Yes, it is right. I don't need to stringify. That is why I got white spaces. My confusion came from the documentation of the module body-parser: Express/Connect top-level generic example:`app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})`

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it this way you can remove the extra quotes which you create by using stringify after the split by removing them from the array.
Note this will only handle the quotes (").

```js
var arr = JSON.stringify('something',null,2).split('');
console.log(arr); // with quotes
for(i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(arr[i] === '\"') {
 arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(arr); // without quotes
```